# I am trying to write js code to display an image in a div using onmouseover event

Tags: javascript

```js
function display(displayPic) {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.innerHTML = displayPic.alt;
  image.style.backgroundImage = "url(displayPic.src)";
}
```

```css
/*Name this external file gallery.css*/

body {
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="display(this)">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="display(this)">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="display(this)">
```

The backgroundImage property is not working when you mouseover the image, though the displayPic.alt works fine.

the code is meant to display on the image div, the currently hovered image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were so close, just change this line:

```
image.style.backgroundImage = "url("+displayPic.src+")";
```

Here you can see your code working:

```js
function display(displayPic) {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.innerHTML = displayPic.alt;
  image.style.backgroundImage = "url("+displayPic.src+")";
}
```

```css
/*Name this external file gallery.css*/

body {
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image {
  line-height: 650px;
  width: 575px;
  height: 650px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8e68ff;
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.preview {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 17%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="display(this)">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="display(this)">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="display(this)">
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is the culprit

`image.style.backgroundImage = "url(displayPic.src)";`

What you are basically doing is setting the background image to a url i.e `displayPic.src`, What you intend to do is to pull the `src` from `displayPic`. Hence you need to concat it properly.

Change it to

`image.style.backgroundImage = "url("+displayPic.src+")";`

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the URL in a variable beforehand:

```
function display(displayPic) {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var urlString = 'url(' + displayPic.src + ')';
  image.innerHTML = displayPic.alt;
  image.style.backgroundImage = urlString;
}
```

Working Example: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0ogdd8/2/)

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct so that it can benefit others.